# left join with up to one row in the right table in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Hifriends, I have one customer table and one relationship table where I keep the customers I send survey link to. The same survey may have been sent to the same customer more than once. Or, some customers may not have sent any survey links. my goal is to bring all the customers once, and if some of these customers have been sent a questionnaire, I want to bring only the one which created date is biggest. The number of records must be equal to the number of customers. I wrote the query, but it is very difficult to translate linq or. Can you help.

this is query what I wrote

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer c
 LEFT JOIN dbo.SurveyCustomers sc ON sc.SurveyCustomerId =
(
SELECT A.SurveyCustomerId
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM dbo.SurveyCustomers sc1
    WHERE sc1.STATUS = 1
          AND sc1.IsActive = 1
          AND sc1.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
          AND sc1.SurveyId = 1207
          AND sc1.STATUS = 1
          AND sc1.IsActive = 1
    ORDER BY sc1.CreatedDate DESC
) A
)
WHERE c.IsActive = 1
  AND c.STATUS = 1;
```

**Customer table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
[CustomerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[CustomerTitle] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
[CustomerEmail] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Status] [bit] NOT NULL)
```

**SurveyCustomer**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyCustomers](
[SurveyCustomerId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[SurveyId] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
[CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY,
[GuidId] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to getting the same result.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Customer c
 OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM dbo.SurveyCustomers sc1
    WHERE sc1.STATUS = 1
          AND sc1.IsActive = 1
          AND sc1.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
          AND sc1.SurveyId = 1207
    ORDER BY sc1.CreatedDate DESC
) A
WHERE c.IsActive = 1
  AND c.STATUS = 1;
```

and linq equivalent:

```
Customers.SelectMany(c => SurveyCustomers
                        .Where(sc1 => 
                            sc1.Status == true 
                            && sc1.IsActive == true
                            && sc1.CustomerId == c.CustomerId
                            && sc1.SurveyId == 1207 )
                        .OrderByDescending(sc1 => sc1.CreatedDate)
                        .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty(), 
                    (c, sc) => new { c, sc })
.ToList()
```

Comment: thanks bro, I have never used outer apply before. I loved it a lot. But linq equivalent  is getting an error in where clause

Comment: Can you write the exception message?

Comment: I changed SurveyCustomers -> entity.SurveyCustomers.No problem now. I will try immediately and accept the answer. Çok teşekkür ederim:)

Comment: I have tried sql is working very well like what I want. But linq part  didn't bring right null record.

Comment: thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted.I accept the answer. You can also updown the question if you like.

Answer (score 0):

For this cases, GROUP BY clause is what you need:

```
SELECT c.SurveyCustomerId, MAX( /* THE MAX YOU WANT TO GET */)
FROM dbo.Customer c
 LEFT JOIN dbo.SurveyCustomers sc ON sc.SurveyCustomerId = A.SurveyCustomerId
GROUP BY c.SurveyCustomerId
WHERE c.IsActive = 1 AND c.STATUS = 1 /*AND OTHER CONDITIONS */;
```

Further reading on GROUP BY clasue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Update: Sorry missed the LINQ part: You should can do something like this:

```
public class SurveyCustomer
    {
        public int SurveyCustomerId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Survey> Surveys { get; set; }
    }

    public class Survey
    {
        public int SurveyId { get; set; }
    }

    public class SurveyCustomerReadModel
    {
        public int SurveyCustomerId { get; set; }

        public int LastSurveyId { get; set; }
    }

    public class SurveyCustomerRepository
    {
        public List<SurveyCustomer> SurveyCustomers { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SurveyCustomerReadModel> GetSurveyCustomerReadModel()
        {
            return this.SurveyCustomers
                .Select(sc => new SurveyCustomerReadModel
                {
                    SurveyCustomerId = sc.SurveyCustomerId,
                    LastSurveyId = sc.Surveys.Max(/* SOME CRITERIA FOR DEFINING THE MAX*/).SurveyId
                });
        }
    }
```

Regards!

Comment: I also edited the question. Sorry for this. I have forgotten

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var finalSurveyCustomers = from customer in Customers
                           join sc in SurveyCustomers on customer.CustomerId equals sc.SurveyCustomerId into leftCustomers
                           from leftCustomer in leftCustomers.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { LeftId = customer.Id, SurveyId = leftCustomer ?? 0 }; // can use int.Max or int.Min
```

Comment: My brother I have editted the question. I am sorry for this.